# How can I get the hourly weather from openweathermap.org?

Tags: python, json, api, weather-api

Right now, I've only been able to request the weather for the current time. However, I want to request the current weather and the weather every hour after that.

[image: This is sort of what i want]

Like this

To find the current weather I used https://openweathermap.org/current, but I'm trying to use https://openweathermap.org/api/hourly-forecast for hourly data but when I looked at the example .json I couldn't figure out how to change the time to get the weather for that time.

This is an example of how I'm getting the data for current weather:

```
combined = city + ',' + country
weatherkey = '****'
url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
params = {'APPID' : weatherkey, 'q' : combined, 'units' : 'metric'}
response = requests.get(url, params = params)
weather = response.json()

desc = string.capwords(str(weather['weather'][0]['description']))
temp = str(round(weather['main']['temp'], 1)) + '°C'

print(desc)
print(temp)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the onecall API:

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall
```

That allows you to get current weather and forecasts based on minute, hourly, daily & alerts. You can tailor what you get back using the exclude parameter:

```
&exclude=daily,minutely,current,alerts
```

Example:

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=-41.211128&lon=174.908081&exclude=daily,minutely,current,alerts&units=metric&appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

where the xxxx are your API key. From there, you need to refer to the documentation for the response format and parse the json.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like https://openweathermap.org/api/hourly-forecast will give you a list of forecasts.

Look at the list.dt value which is "Time of data forecasted, Unix, UTC".

Iterate over the list and find the time value which matches (as closely as possible) the time you're interested in. You have to work with the values that the API gives you, it is not a good idea to guess which forecasts exists, instead you have to check each list.dt value until you find the one you are looking for (if you are looking for a specific forecast).

For example, let's say you're looking for the forecast for Wednesday, August 5, 2020 14:00:00 (UTC), which is 1596636000 in unix time.

(excuse the pythonesque code, see this as pseudo code)

```
requested_time = 1596636000
for forecast in api_response["list"]:
   if forecast.dt => requested_time:
      print forecast
      break
```

Comment: How exactly would I do that because I don't know how to change that value. I was thinking you could just add 3600 to the Unix time to push it an hour ahead and get the weather for that time.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some more details and an example, hope it helps!